# TeXMaker, LaTeX problem or memory?

Tags: texmaker, ubuntu, bugs

If I want to compile in Ubuntu TexLive2013 tex file with "ł" in proof enviroment, if "ł" is outside, then is OK:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 7558) in paragraph at lines 17--18
\OT4/cmr/m/n/10.95 ho-mo-mor-fizm $\OML/cmm/m/it/10.95 x[] \OMS/cmsy/m/n/10.95
! \OML/cmm/m/it/10.95 H[]$ \OT4/cmr/m/n/10.95 prze-kszta�ca $\OML/cmm/m/it/10.9
5 u \OMS/cmsy/m/n/10.95 ! \OML/cmm/m/it/10.95 u[]$ \OT4/cmr/m/n/10.95 oraz $\OM
L/cmm/m/it/10.95 v \OMS/cmsy/m/n/10.95 !
[]
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,b5paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm} %proof
\usepackage[polish]{babel} %musi być po amssymb
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT4]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\sloppy

\begin{proof}
Niech $x,x \in x(x_x)$ oraz $x',x' \in V(H_l)$. Niech homomorfizm $x_l \to H_l$ przekształca $u \to u'$ oraz $v \to v'$. Niech $x(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n),(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)x$ będzie krawędzią grafu $G_1,G_2,\ldots,\ldots,G_n$.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It's 21 December 2017 today, yet you seem to be running TeXLive2013 on your system. Any chance you could download and install TeXLive2017?

Comment: @Mico Do you mean it was not possible to compile with "ł" back in the old ages of 2013? ZYX You could add a Minimal Working Example to try reproducing your error. Also you can monitor the memory used by different processes.

Comment: @anderstood - I suspect it's quite possible that a TeXLive2013 may not run flawlessly if the operating system has been updated significantly in the meantime. E.g., I strongly suspect that the executables and libraries of a MacTeX2013 system won't run properly on a Mac running the latest MacOS (10.13.2 "High Sierra"). A separate, and probably more relevant, reason for upgrading to TeXlive2017 would be that so many packages have been improved and extended significantly over the past 4+ years. Why miss out on these improvements?

Comment: @Mico I realized during an article submission that some journals (at least some from Springer) are still running TexLive 2014 !! :O

Comment: How to check it? (TexLive2013)

Comment: If "ł" is outside proof env., then is OK.

Comment: @anderstood - Ouch!! (And they're probably still running under Windows 2000 or Windows XP...)

Comment: @ZYX It shows in the bottom of the first picture. You can also check the `log` files, or run `latex -v` in a terminal.

Comment: Hard to help without a MWE...

Comment: It is interesting it works, if I remove something, but not always :) For an example, if I remove  sloppy it work. If I remove last two symbiols _n - do not work.

Comment: There are some red caption on the third picture?

Comment: Possibly irrelevant, but `OT4` is obsolete and you should be using `T1`: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.